# Determining when to create a new JavaScript file (organizing source code)

Tags: javascript

I'm about to set out on a large map application project that is going to be around 5,000 lines of JavaScript in total.

My normal way of going about a project like this would be to create a single file called 'main.js' and then include everything all in that one file. I think it's about time I broke out of this habbit and started to store the JavaScript files more sensibly by splitting up components into more JavaScript files. Is this a good idea? I want the project to be more organized.

My question is, what's the best practice for doing this? When should I say "Hmm, this should probably go in its own file". Is there a general rule of thumb I should stick to when deciding to put code in a new file?

Comment: Yes, I'd break out of that habit.  Learn how the module pattern works so you can keep the global namespace clean.  As for groupings, that's a matter of experience, style, and taste.  Like things should go together.  Functions that handle specific areas should be put in the same module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should break your code up into separate files.  There are lots and lots of different ways to decide what should go in a given file - it all depends upon what your code is and how you think it can be best organized.  Here are some of the possible ways you can organize things:

1. Code in reusable objects where similar objects are combined into a module and a small module is contained in one file. Then each file is a module.
2. Group a set of objects and functions related to one particular type of functionality in one file.  For example if you have a set of functions that help you do animation, then you might group all those together in one file.
3. If you have a set of utility functions that are reusable across a number of different applications, group those together in one or more files so they can be more easily used in multiple projects without reorganizing them.
4. When considering reusability, put the smallest chunks that you may want to reuse into their own files so you can include only what is desired in your future projects.  Also make sure any dependent functions, utilities, etc... are also separately includeable in their own files.  The idea is that in a future project you should just be able to include existing files without reorganizing the code and without having to include a bunch of stuff that you don't need.
5. Put code that is specific to this particular application and/or this specific user interface into it's own files so it is separate from other parts that you may be more likely to want to reuse in other applications.

---

Also keep in mind that the most efficient deployment strategy is to recombine most of your separate files into a single, larger file that is minimized as this is more efficient for a browser to download and cache and improves the performance of your web site.  This recombination of files should be an automatated build step that concatenates files together before minimizing the combined result.  It isn't something you do with your editor as you should keep your files separate in your source control system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do separate your project into files. I'd use the same guidelines you've probably used with other programming languages. Good programming techniques are more or less universal. It doesn't matter what language you're using.

Try to break your project up into reusable objects. Keep each object focused on a defined task. That way you'll have a library of objects you can use in future projects.

Pick up a copy of "JavaScript: The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford